# MS Teams Windows 10 Client: "Update your Browser" message Within Client

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-teams

I've just come back from a holiday vacation and launched the local Microsoft Teams client on my Windows 10 (**LTSC** 2021/21H2) PC. After providing credentials, I get a screen that indicates that I need to set up some kind of additional security feature, and the I click "next". The next screen that I see is shown below. It seems that the MS teams app itself is not capable of displaying the content of this screen. I'm looking for a way to proceed, **ideally without installing Edge** - which I'm not even sure is possible in the LTSC version of Windows.

I recognize that I might be able to perform whatever setup is required through a standalone browser, and I'll do that if there turns out to be no other option, but I'd like to explore whether a proper workaround within the Teams client can be found.

I'm open to any suggestions that might bring about a workaround or a fix so that I can use MS Teams as a self-contained app rather than in a browser. Any ideas are appreciated.[image: MS Teams App in Win10]

Comment: Can you try a different and more up to date host machine?  iPhone, tablet, and so on

Comment: @John This is the latest teams client on the latest version of Windows 10 LTSC - so no, there is nothing newer for me to try.